# jquery menu with scrollbar issues

Tags: jquery, menu

I want to create a jquery live search that returns multiple results from different tables in the database. eg i have a news, members, videos table in the database. it will be built based on the quick search found at http://www.veepiz.com/afrostar.php. the search control in center column(not right). i want when some one is searching it returns a vertical menu showing

news (8 articles) >>
videos (10 found) >>
members (3 found) >>

when some one hovers over news... a submenu showing the news articles found is shown. the problem comes when over 100 results are added... i want a menu system that has a scroller incase a lot of returned results... is this approach ok? i want a central place where some one can search for everything. something similar to what facebook did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really will come down to how you are displaying the items on hover a scroll bar might be ok visually.  What you might want to do is only display the first 10 or so and have a link that takes them to a page that lists them all in a nice paged format.

So technically you can definitely do this but from a usability perspective it might not be the best idea.  It really comes down to how much content each item is showing, how they are seperated, if a scrollbar on this revealed list looks out of place, ..etc.